# How would I create a javascript upload modal box?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, textbox

how can I make a java script modal box that uploads an image to the site and then inserts the url into a textbox in html/php? I think this is what they are called, I mean the "pop up box inside the browser thing"!

Thanks,
Cameron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[davidwalsh.name/facebook-lightbox](http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-lightbox)

Have a look at the link. It may be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Use Fancybox or colorbox, they are simple and easy to integrate

Comment: I know about these but how would I upload things through them and then insert it into the text box?